# DNS Resolution over Network Interface

Tags: ubuntu, dns, network-interface, routing, systemd-resolved

I am trying to route specific site DNS queries through specific network interface.
I have private site which is accessible only through specific network interface `enp39s0 (eth)` and my default internet should be routed through `wifi` network interface.

Currently this is my configuration

```
❯ systemd-resolve --status
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: foreign
      DNS Domain: corp.private-site.com labcorp.private-site.com private-site.com

Link 2 (enp39s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.2.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.2.1 10.64.0.1
        DNS Domain: corp.private-site.com labcorp.private-site.com private-site.com

Link 3 (wlo1)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 8.8.4.4
       DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

Link 5 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

Configuration done through `nm-connection-editor`
[image]

DNS lookup query

```
❯ dig k8s0292274-node1.lab3.private-site.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.15-Ubuntu <<>> k8s0292274-node1.lab3.private-site.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 52201
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;k8s0292274-node1.lab3.private-site.com. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
private-site.com XXXXXXXXXXX

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 05 09:59:21 IST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 134
```

IP Route list

```
10.64.0.1 via 192.168.2.1 dev enp39s0 proto static metric 1
```

Please help me to route all my queries related to `*.private-site.com` should be routed through `enp39s0` including DNS.

Comment: It seems to me that you’re mixing apples and oranges.  You need (1) to have a local DNS server that maps `xxxxx.private-site.com` addresses to the appropriate local IP addresses, and (2) set up the route tables so that IP connections to the private site go through the necessary interface.  I believe that you should do these independently.  It looks like you already have a local DNS server.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that you are not using the resolved stub as your nameserver in resolv.conf. Check whether it's a file or a symlink and its content.